# nodejs Mysql how can i use different database？

Tags: node.js

im new for nodejs ,i make two different models, when they initialize i want to use different database to get data here is connect code:

```
try {
        connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: this.config.host,
            user: this.config.user,
            password: this.config.password,
            database: this.config.database
        });
    } catch (errorMessage) {
        logger.error('Error connecting to MySQL database on ' + this.config.database);
    }
    connection.connect(function(err){
        /**
         * Connection needs some time to "get ready?"
         */
        setTimeout(function() {
            if(err){

                deferred.reject(err);
            } else {
                logger.info('Connected to database' + this.config);
                this.connection = connection;
                deferred.resolve();
            }
        }, 1000 );
    });
```

init function:

```
this.init = function(){

    var deferred = Q.defer();
    this.connect()
        .then(fun1)
        .then(fun2)
        .then(function(){
            deferred.resolve();
        },function(err){
            deferred.reject(err);
        });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

and this is singleton function (i think it useless):

```
myclass.getInstance = function(){
    if(this.instance === null){

        this.instance = new myclass();

        this.instance.init().then(function(){
            this.connection.end();

        }, function(error){

            process.exit();
        });

    }
    return this.instance;
}
```

these code use in two different models ,when one get data the other user old connection instance (different database) , how can i fix?

Comment: did you resolve this?